# Successfully registered COM DLL is not being listed in "Insert ActiveX control" dialog of visual studio

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, com, atl, tstcon32

I have created a COM DLL using the ATL project (Composite object) which basically has one tree control (which is a part of VS toolbox) within a dialog.

After registering it, I'm trying to insert it in a dialog based MFC/ATL application by using the standard approach of using "Insert ActiveX control" dialog of Visual Studio.

But the problem here is, even after its successful registration it is not getting listed in the "Insert ActiveX control" dialog. So I'm not able to insert it in the container dialog.

**Alternatives that I've tried and that worked:**

In a tool provided by Microsoft to test such controls i.e., "ActiveX control test container"(TSTCON32.exe), my COM DLL is getting listed properly and I'm able to use it.

**Alternatives that I've tried and that not worked:**

1. Un-registering the DLL and re-registering it back.
2. Rebooting the PC.

So, any help on this regard is warmly appreciated.

Couple more details:

1. Both ".idl" and ".rgs" file looks proper.
2. I will share my project if it is needed.

Comment: Did you register an ActiveX control with the same bitness as that of the designated consumer project?

Comment: Yes. I have registered the ActiveX control with the same bitness as that of the designated consumer project.

Comment: ATL projects produce an additional proxy dll with PS added to its name. Do you have it created and have you tried to register it as well?

Comment: @VuVirt I have not tried registering the proxy stub (PS). I will try registering it and check.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an activeX control to your project, you must specify the ProgID in the ATL control wizard.[image]